# State Monad then (>>)

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I would like to know the definition of `>>` for the Haskell state monad.

By my guess it pass one state to another:

```
(>>) :: State s a -> State s b -> State s b
State a >> State b = State $ \x -> b $ snd ( a x )
```

or

```
State a >> State b = State $ b . snd . a
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much right. `>>` is actually more general than you suggest, but you can certainly use it with the type signature you indicate. If you're using `State` from its usual home, `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict`, or its home away from home, `Control.Monad.State.Strict`, `State` is actually just a type synonym:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

where `Identity` is from `Data.Functor.Identity` and defined

```
newtype Identity x = Identity x
```

and `StateT` is defined

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}
```

So `State s a` is just a newtype wrapper around

```
s -> Identity (a, s)
```

This is essentially the same as the definition you imagine, but it allows `State s` to be compatible with the *monad transformer* `StateT s`, which is used to add state to arbitrary `Monad`s.

```
instance Monad m => Monad (StateT s m) where
  return a = StateT $ \s -> return (a, s)
  StateT g >>= f = StateT $ \s -> g s >>= \(r,s') -> runStateT (f r) s'
```

So

```
  StateT g >> StateT h = StateT $ \s -> g s >>= \(_,s') -> h s'

                       = StateT $ \s -> h $ snd $ runIdentity (g s)
                       = StateT $ h . snd . runIdentity . g
```

---

#### Irrelevant side note

The definition of `StateT` annoys me, because in my opinion it puts the elements of the pairs in the wrong order. Why wrong? Because mapping over `(a, s)` changes `s` while leaving `a` alone, and that is not what happens when mapping over a state transformer. End result: poor intuition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: I'd +1 for that side note alone.  That explains why I always found the `s -> (a, s)` definition backwards!

Answer (score 2):

I think [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#State_monads) gives a definition for `(>>=)` for the `State` monad:

```
m >>= f = \r -> let (x, s) = m r in (f x) s
```

Since `(>>)` is implemented in terms of `(>>=)` as follows:

```
m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
```

one can derive the definition for `(>>)` for the state monad:

```
m >> k = \r -> let (x, s) = m r in ((\_ -> k) x) s
```

or when removing the noise:

```
m >> k = \r -> let (x, s) = m r in k s
```

Now since `x` does not play a part in the `in` clause, you can indeed use `snd` to get `s`, which can thus be rewritten to:

```
m >> k = \r -> k $ snd m r
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, is your example use type synonym of monad?

Comment: What do you mean with type synonym? `Monad` is not a `type`/`data`, it is a `class`.

Comment: For example `m>>k where m, k :: State s a`